# How to execute the SQL Log() function in LINQ?

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have a SQL view that uses the LOG() function.  I'm trying to replace this view with a LINQ query, but can't find any reference re: this function.  I'd greatly appreciate an example or pointing me to a good LINQ reference site that would help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[] names = { 1,2,3 };

var namesList = names.ToList(); // to get enumerable query

(from e in namesList select Math.Log(e)).Dump();
```

As far as learning Linq, I highly recommend the [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) tool, which has a free version and many embedded samples and exercises.

Comment: Thanks Nathan.   I tried Math.Log(), but I receive this error.  

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double Log(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: I see.  The reason is because there is no exact translation for LOG as a store query. You can force to evaluate by first loading the query and then apply .Log on the query itself by using .ToList   I modified my answer to reflect this. Please let me know if this helps.  of course, toList is going to bring the complete dataset up, so this is not great workaround if your result is large.

Comment: Use `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToList()`

Comment: Is there a difference in the use of AsEnumerable or ToList in this simple case? I was using ToList to force the query to materialize the dataset so Math.Log would run at the client. I guess AsEnumerable would do the same but with a slight delay in loading?